# Return partial linq query from method - how to declare return type

Tags: c#, linq, subsonic3, anonymous-types

I have a linq query written in method syntax.  I need to create a very similar method with just some changes to the final Select.

Is it possible to return the partial Linq query from a method so I dont duplicate the code?  The issue I have is finding the "Type" of the query to mark the method with.

If I use query.GetType(), it returns (cut down version) :

```
SubSonic.Linq.Structure.Query`1[<>f__AnonymousType18`6[advert,client]]
```

I tried to create a return type:

```
SubSonic.Linq.Structure.Query<advert, client> query = new SubSonic.Linq.Structure.Query<advert, client>();
```

However I receive the error:

```
Error   20  Using the generic type 'SubSonic.Linq.Structure.Query<T>' requires '1' type arguments
```

**So I guess I am asking how to declare a return type that is a Subsonic Query containing an anonymous type containing a number of objects?** (2 in my example)

Please excuse my simple example:

eg:

```
internal ????? GetQueryBody(string param1, string param2){
    /*  buld the linq query here */
}

internal List<Booking> GetSearchResultsOne(string param1, string param2){
  var query = this.GetQueryBody(string param1, string param2);
  var res = query.Select( db => new Booking { /*fields */).ToList();
  return res;
}

internal List<BookingData> GetSearchResultsTwo(string param1, string param2){
  var query = this.GetQueryBody(string param1, string param2);
  var res = query.Select( db => new BookingData { /*fields*/).ToList();
  return res;
}
```

Thank you for your time,

Yohimbo

Comment: Assuming I got it right, could it be IQueryable<WhateverTheQueryIsOperatingOn>?

Comment: re using : "IQueryable<WhateverTheQueryIsOperatingOn>".  I guess that's my question - the WhateverTheQueryIsOperatingOn is an anonymous object containing 2 objects.  How would I express that?   IQueryable<??<advert,client>> ?

Answer (score 1):

Use `IEnumerable<T>` to return a query.

About the anonymous type: If a type is anonymous, how should another methode know about it? Read more [here](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2009/01/09/horrible-grotty-hack-returning-an-anonymous-type-instance.aspx). To solve the problem, give your anonymous type a name by creating a class.

If you only want to return two types you could also return a tuple: Then `T` is `Tuple<advert,client>`. You can create a tuple by

```
var t = new Tuple<advert,client>(client, advert);
```

Comment: I tried using IQueryable as the return type, however, the compiler said:**"Error 26 'System.Linq.IQueryable' does not contain a definition for 'Select' and no extension method 'Select' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Linq.IQueryable' could be found"**

Comment: re using : "IEnumerable<T>".  I guess that's my question - the T is an anonymous object containing 2 objects.  How would I express that?  Like IEnumerable<??<advert,client>> ?

Comment: re: "About the anonymous type" link.  I cant create a class to wrap it - it's what the Subsonic Linq provider is returning when I perform query.GetType(): "SubSonic.Linq.Structure.Query`1[<>f__AnonymousType18`6[advert,client]]"...  Thank you for the help though

Comment: Take a look at the tuple solution, could be better in your case. You could run a select on the result of the Subsonic Linq provider and fill it.

Comment: I think this is more an issue with Subsonic query provider.  The return type needs to be of type 
SubSonic.Linq.Structure.Query`1[<>f__AnonymousType18`6[advert,client]].  If I return a tuple, I can no longer perform the rest of the linq projection, as it's be a tuple rather than an IQueryable (well SubSonic.Linq.Structure.Query which implements IQueryable).  Thank you for your help though.

Answer (score 1):

Answer 1: You can't do it because Booking and BookingData are different types so the expression trees are different.

Answer 2: Assuming you can find a common base class, there are two approaches to your question.

1. The 'type' of what a Linq Query acts on is actually an `Expression<TDelegate>`. You can construct Expression trees and store them and manipulate them, and then use them where needed.
2. The 'argument' for your final Select() is actually an `Expression<Func<TSource, TResult>>`. You can use any function in that location as long as it conforms to that delegate.

In other words, you can store the entire pre-formed expression trees from the top, or you can store one tree and substitute the bit at the bottom. There isn't enough in your sample for me to write the code, and you still have to resolve that fatal flaw.